# I'm getting warning while traning the data using logistic regression algorithm

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression

I'm training one dataset of numbers to classify the numbers using logistic regression multiclass classification. By using this code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
digits = load_digits()

plt.gray() 
for i in range(5):
    plt.matshow(digits.images[i])

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data,digits.target, test_size=0.2)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm doing this in jupyter notebook when I execute the cell

```
   model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get warning like

```
C:\Users\Shubham Teke\anaconda3\envs\allenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:764: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
LogisticRegression()
```

So what is this warning and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the model training is stopped by `max_iter`.
That is, the parameters of the model are not converged, but iteration becomes `max_iter`.

The solution is simple. Increase your `max_iter`.

e.g.,

```
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 100000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is warning, not error. You need to increase max iteration number.

default value is 100. Try this one

```
LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
```

or increase more than 1000